# Consulta de php a sqlserver no muestra campos null, vacios o cero

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola estoy mostrando los resultados en php de una consulta en sql.
Me muestra bien los campos que tienen algun numero, pero los que contienen cero no me los esta mostrando, que puedo usar para poder mostrar tambien cuando sea cero.
El siguiente es mi codigo donde muestro los valores

```
  <?php
  foreach ($registros as $fila) :
  if( $fila->GN_YELLOW and $fila->CIDESC_MP==="INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY"){
    echo  '<a href="pagina2.php" >';
    echo '<button type="button" class="elementoyellow" >';
      echo $fila->CIDESC_MP;
    echo $fila->GN_YELLOW;
    echo '</button>';
    echo '</a>';
        }else {}

       endforeach;
        ?>
```

Esto es lo que obtengo como vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que contiene la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta remover esto  `$fila->GN_YELLOW and`

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias